# LWJGL Keyboard getEventKey() returns 0

Tags: lwjgl, keyboard-events

I have got a trouble with LWJGL (I'm new in it) and keyboard handling: I need to get keys pressing, and so on, there is my code:

```
while (alive) {
   Display.update();
   while (Keyboard.next()) {
      System.out.println(Keyboard.getEventKey());
   }
   // Some draw calls
}
```

That's work OK with numbers, space, backspace and non-printable keys: ESC gives 1, Space gives 57, 9 gives 10, etc, but pressed letter-keys returns 0 (maybe, it means CHAR_NONE const), without reference to my keyboard layout: EN, RU or something else. Through getEventCharacter() returns valid symbols in both layouts.

That may be issue of my Arch (3.14 x64) or something nearby, I think, or have I got a mistake in code? Or may it be a bug?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution: that's in setxkbmap: I've just

```
setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us
```

and everything is normal now.